# Should I wrap a shared message queue in a mutex when I am writing to it?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, zephyr-rtos

I am building a multi-threaded application, and wanted to follow good practice when using a message queue to build a thread-safe system.

I have not been able to produce a problem with not using the mutex.

Should I wrap message queue put/get operations in a mutex when the message queue is being shared and written to by multiple threads?

Comment: Based on your tag, I assume your question is about Zephyr RTOS? From a quick look in the source `kernel/msg_q.c`, in function `z_impl_k_msgq_put`, the first thing it does is call `k_spin_lock(&msgq->lock)`. So, it seems to do its own locking.